# Display image from realpath in php

Tags: php, image, path

We want to display the image from the realpath and the code is as follows

```
$img = 'F:\xampp\htdocs\Examples\header.png';
echo "<img src='".$img."'>";
```

but the image is not displaying and the src is showing as `http://localhost/Examples/F:\xampp\htdocs\Examples\header.png`
how can we display the image from above path `$img`. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do this with alone `PHP`,  you have to do it with some `JS`. Because `PHP` is server-side language and your image is on client-side, So it's impossible with `PHP`

Comment: we can display the files located at client side say `$file = "F:/xampp/htdocs/Examples/*.zip";

foreach(glob($file) as $fl)
{
 echo $fl."****<br>";
}` so the above code displays the all zip files in the given directory, so why cant we display the image in same folder

Comment: You should use the relative path of file (to the root of your program). So, the image should be in public path or you should read the content of image, and put the base64 encoding of the content in the src attribute.